# Power automate cloud flow cannot be saved with the SharePoint list trigger

Tags: power-automate, sharepoint-list

When a flow is created with a trigger "When an item is created or modified" for Sharepoint. I received below error message and flow is not saved.

```
Flow save failed with code 'DynamicOperationRequestClientFailure' and message 
'The dynamic operation request to API 'sharepointonline' operation 'GetTable' failed 
with status code 'BadRequest'. This may indicate invalid input parameters. 
Error response: { "status": 400, "message": "The required field \"Current Program\"
 data type is not supported\r\nclientRequestId: 
c6f2075f-3325-468d-a6e6-ad05e48f3d5a\r\nserviceRequestId: 
c6f2075f-3325-468d-a6e6-ad05e48f3d5a" }'.
```

I am using Sharepoint Online and Power automate.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've recently had the same problem. We have a flow that did roughly the same as yours that was working fine for almost a year. A couple of weeks ago it stopped working, giving the same error.

What did the trick in my case was the following: the field it referenced in the error message was a lookup column. The user who executed/owned the Flow had no permissions to view/edit this table. Once he was given permissions to the table the field referenced, everything worked as before.

Comment: It did not help in my case